# ARM - Memory map leakages

Tags: arm, embedded, microcontroller

Lets assume that we are using MCU with ARM Cortex-M4, 256KB of FLASH and 64KB of RAM. This CPU contains memory map like showed below:

[image]

As I understand it correctly, the memory map tells us what are the maximum sizes of memories, that limits MCU vendor and where that CPU will look for it. For example, we cannot use Cortex-M4 with FLASH memory above 512MB, right?

In that situation, we have 64KB of RAM, and the limit is 512MB. My question is - does CPU know about that? Does it have any safety mechanisms, that will avoid trying to access beyond that 64KB of RAM (stack overflow) by halting in any way? Or maybe the CPU will work in way like "I have that boundaries, I will move around these if necessary". I know, that compilers may provide some information, that can aware the programmer.

Comment: The CPU does not know about the size of memory connected.  It writes the address that it wishes to access to the bus.  If nothing on the bus matches that address then you might get a bus fault interrupt or some other undesirable behaviour, or it might just ignore it and carry on.  Exact details vary depending on implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> As I understand it correctly, the memory map tells us what are the maximum sizes of memories, that limits MCU vendor and where that CPU will look for it.

Yes.

> For example, we cannot use Cortex-M4 with FLASH memory above 512MB, right?

Normally the flash is the part between address 0x0 and 0x1FFFFFFF. Meaning 512MB indeed (`1024*1024*512=0x20000000`). Which is a ridiculously large size for a Cortex M.

> My question is - does CPU know about that?

Yes and no. The physical memory will exist where the vendor placed it. This can at some extent be remapped through the linker script.

The Cortex M does not have an advanced MMU/MPU with support virtual memory, meaning all memory is physical addresses. It does however keep track of various invalid accesses through hardware exceptions. From ARM/Keil AN209 *Using Cortex-M3/M4/M7 Fault Exceptions*:

> **Fault exception handlers**
> Fault exceptions trap illegal memory accesses and illegal program behavior. The following conditions are detected by fault exception handlers:
>
> - HardFault: is the default exception and can be triggered because of an error during exception processing, or because an exception cannot be managed by any other exception mechanism.
> - MemManage: detects memory access violations to regions that are defined in the Memory Management Unit (MPU); for example, code execution from a memory region with read/write access only.
> - BusFault: detects memory access errors on instruction fetch, data read/write, interrupt vector fetch, and register stacking (save/restore) on interrupt (entry/exit).
> - UsageFault: detects execution of undefined instructions, unaligned memory access for load/store multiple. When enabled, divide-by-zero and other unaligned memory accesses are detected.

Answer (score 1):

No the CPU does not know - you specify the memory map in the linker script, and the link will fail if your code and/or data cannot be located in the stated available memory.

If you specify the memory map incorrectly, the linker may locate code/data in non-existent memory and when you load it, parts will be missing.  For the flash programming very likely the programming tool will fail if it is set to read-back verify the code.

Also if you dynamically load code to non existent memory, or access  memory not allocated by the linker at run-time, the results are non-deterministic, other than it won't do anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

The CPU cannot know as everyone has said.  The MCU vendor buys the processor ip from arm, as well as ip from other vendors as well as creates some of their own if nothing else the glue that holds the modules together.   The flash itself is likely from some third party.

Some chip designers wrap around, this is not uncommon in hardware or software, for example the part may have 16Kbytes starting at 0x08000000 this is the CHIP companies decision ARM has little to do with it other than what you have found that they define wide ranges (likely for caching and other options within their domain).  16K is 16384 bytes or 0x4000 so 14 bits of address.  There is likely an address decoder that sees some number of upper bits 0x08...and sends that request to the flash logic, then at the flash logic it would not suprise me to see the lower 14 address bits stripped off and used meaning if you were to address 0x08000000 and 0x08008000 you may get the same 0x0000 offset/address in the flash.

Some engineers may choose to look at those upper bits and declare a fault.

You have to examine this on a case by case basis not just an stm32 for example but each family of stm32, for every datasheet basically.  (And there is no reason to expect this level of detail is documented by the chip vendor).

The arm cortex-m as with all processors are very very stupid they do what the bits tell them to do it is our responsibility to feed the a sequential trail of working instructions, just like laying track in front of a train  you can lay a lot of track in the wrong place, with gaps, etc.  If not per the rules of the train then the train will crash or fail in some way.

The others have mentioned the linker script, and to be clear the linker script does not just magically somehow know what chip you have, ultimately you, the programmer are responsible for telling the toolchain to build programs that follow the rules of the cpu AND CHIP, to be successful.  So the right architecture instructions (or a subset, cortex-m0 instructions (armv6m will run on a cortex-m4 (armv7m)).  And the linker script needs to define addresses for read only and read write areas that match the chip (not the core, the chip as they are in charge of that definition).  And then barring 100 other ways you can fail.   It will run.

You are ultimately responsible but most folks grab an sdk or sandbox of some sort and hope for the best, blind faith in others.  Gnu and llvm tools are fully capable to be used by you directly without these third parties, but then you are fully responsible for getting everything right.